# Jmeter - combine two variables into one

Tags: json, foreach, jmeter

I have extract Json element in previous step (which created an array) and I want to access specific element inside using counter variable (inside foreach).
this is the element that holds the array:

```
SB_names
```

and inside the 'Foreach' I have created a counter with variable - 'counter'.
now, in the name of the http request I'm trying to access each element of the array in each iteration.
this works for example:

```
${__V(${SB_names_1})}
```

but I want to do something like this (which currently is not working):

```
${__V(${SB_names_${counter}})}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
${__V(SB_names_${counter})}
```

> For example, if one has variables A1,A2 and N=1:
>
> **${A1}** - works OK
>
> **${A${N}}** - does not work (nested variable reference)
>
> **${__V(A${N})}** - works OK. A${N} becomes A1, and the __V function returns the value of A1

References:

- [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) manual
- [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) - series of articles with extended information on using JMeter functions